# How to configure multiple instances of a program to write to different log files in Serilog?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, logging, serilog

I have an Core 7 application that uses Serilog and Serilog.Sink.Files to write to a rolling log file. My question is I want to have two instances of this application running, how can I get both instances to write to a different log file, instead of the same one?

I tried manually specifying the log file names but unfortunately, this does not work since the applications share the same App.config file.

Comment: "this does not work since the applications share the same App.config file" Then how do you want to set the file name? How do you launch the two instances of the programs?

Comment: Append `Guid` to the file name? Pass a parameter to the console app which will determine which file to write to?